# Facebook Login to no longer allow Return Url parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a ASP.Net MVC 5 application that allows users to sign in Via Facebook.   If the User hits a page that they don't have access to they are sent to a login screen with multiple providers (fairly typical) and if they click on the Facebook login it sends them to Facebook so they can login and includes a ReturnURL parameter.

Today when I logged into Facebook and saw notifications from Facebook that they are going to no longer allow additional parameters and said the following OAuth redirect URI would no longer be accepted

[https://www.------.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2FEntry%2FSomePage%2FParam&**provider**=facebook&**sid**=73a76f5551a4e5ab0ae943b9b963fcb](https://www.------.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2FEntry%2FSomePage%2FParam&__provider__=facebook&__sid__=73a76f5551a4e5ab0ae943b9b963fcb)

They plan on making the change in 30 days.   Has anyone else ran into this and how do you forward the user to the correct page.  Not having the ReturnUrl will break the workflow of the site.

Comment: Just put the info into the session instead ...?

Comment: The site is session less.  I could put it in a cookie and return to an intermediary page but it also seems that the change wouldn't allow the sid or provider parameters.

Comment: I think the `state` parameter is except from that restriction, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#stateparam says _"For apps with dynamic redirect URIs, use the state parameter to pass back the dynamic information to a limited number of redirect URIs"_

Comment: It does look like you can put everything into the state parameter.  The authentication framework expects some of the parameters to be in the URL so I have to re-write the url but it looks like it should work.